# Lua Ternary Operations (Code Golfing)

Tags: lua

I'm doing a bit of code golfing, and I've gotten to this:

`for i=1,100 do for j=1,i do if i%j<1 then io.write(j.." ") end end print() end`

Is there any way to get the if statement as an inline? So that it's wrapped into the io.write()

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operation in lua can be mimicked with `and..or` operators:

```
a and b or c
```

is similar to

```
a ? b : c
```

under truthy values. For your case:

```
for i=1,100 do
  for j=1,i do
    io.write( ((i % j) < 1 and j.." " or '')
    -- (i % j) < 1 and io.write(.." ")
  end
  print() -- why print here?
end
```

golfed, it is

```
io.write(i%j<1 and j.." "or'')
```

which saves you 4 characters

Comment: Ahh. I had attempted to use the and/or, but i wasn't entirely sure.

To answer your question, we print() because we want the numbers on a seperate line instead of a long string. Unless there's a shorter way to nextline it in this case

Comment: @SaraMaeBee probably have a temporary buffer, and just print once in the outer loop. But I think it'll be of same length as your current if-block `for i=1,100 do s=''for j=1,i do s=s..(i%j<1 and j.." "or'')end print(s)end`